# Remote connection with ssh - Permission Denied

Tags: linux, ssh

I'm working on ubuntu 12.04(desktop) and installed on it ssh. I would like to have access to my desktop resources using my laptop (win8 64) remotely. On my laptop I've installed cygwin. When I use it at home, via my private network everything works perfectly - no problems with password authentication, permission denied etc.  The problem starts when I trying to connect to my desktop remotely. In order to check my router ip I used whatismyipadress.com site. I think I forwarded my port 22 correctly. I'm playing with it with such way:

1. sudo start ssh (on my desktop)
2. ssh -vv -p 22 kotu@ipadressofrouter

I got such info from my cygwin terminal

```
OpenSSH_6.3, OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/Krystyna/.ssh/config
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 82.160.125.184 [82.160.125.184] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/Krystyna/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/Krystyna/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/Krystyna/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/Krystyna/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/Krystyna/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/Krystyna/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.3
debug1: Remote protocol version 1.99, remote software version OpenSSH_2.3.0_Mikrotik_v2.9
debug1: match: OpenSSH_2.3.0_Mikrotik_v2.9 pat OpenSSH_2.3.0*
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug2: Original cipher proposal: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: Compat cipher proposal: arcfour256,arcfour128,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: Original cipher proposal: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: Compat cipher proposal: arcfour256,arcfour128,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v00@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-rsa
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: arcfour256,arcfour128,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: arcfour256,arcfour128,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,arcfour,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,rijndael128-cbc,rijndael192-cbc,rijndael256-cbc,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,arcfour,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,rijndael128-cbc,rijndael192-cbc,rijndael256-cbc,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-sha1,hmac-md5,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-sha1,hmac-md5,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0
debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-md5
debug1: kex: server->client 3des-cbc hmac-md5 none
debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-md5
debug1: kex: client->server 3des-cbc hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST_OLD(2048) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug2: dh_gen_key: priv key bits set: 208/384
debug2: bits set: 478/1024
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: DSA 7f:74:c1:be:c8:9f:12:b0:44:dd:58:ed:9f:83:2d:8e
debug1: Host '82.160.125.184' is known and matches the DSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/Krystyna/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug2: bits set: 527/1024
debug1: ssh_dss_verify: signature correct
debug2: kex_derive_keys
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug2: key: /home/Krystyna/.ssh/id_rsa (0x0),
debug2: key: /home/Krystyna/.ssh/id_dsa (0x0),
debug2: key: /home/Krystyna/.ssh/id_ecdsa (0x0),
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/Krystyna/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/Krystyna/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/Krystyna/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: Next authentication method: password
kotu1@82.160.125.184's password:
debug2: we sent a password packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
Permission denied, please try again.
kotu1@82.160.125.184's password:
debug2: we sent a password packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
Permission denied, please try again.
```

My sshd_config file:

```
# Package generated configuration file
# See the sshd_config(5) manpage for details
# What ports, IPs and protocols we listen for
Port 22
# Use these options to restrict which interfaces/protocols sshd will bind to
#ListenAddress ::
#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
Protocol 2
# HostKeys for protocol version 2
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
#Privilege Separation is turned on for security
UsePrivilegeSeparation yes
# Lifetime and size of ephemeral version 1 server key
KeyRegenerationInterval 3600
ServerKeyBits 768
# Logging
SyslogFacility AUTH
LogLevel INFO
# Authentication:
LoginGraceTime 120
PermitRootLogin yes
StrictModes yes
RSAAuthentication no
PubkeyAuthentication no
#AuthorizedKeysFile     %h/.ssh/authorized_keys
# Don't read the user's ~/.rhosts and ~/.shosts files
IgnoreRhosts yes
# For this to work you will also need host keys in /etc/ssh_known_hosts
RhostsRSAAuthentication no
# similar for protocol version 2
HostbasedAuthentication no
# Uncomment if you don't trust ~/.ssh/known_hosts for RhostsRSAAuthentication
#IgnoreUserKnownHosts yes
# To enable empty passwords, change to yes (NOT RECOMMENDED)
PermitEmptyPasswords no
# Change to yes to enable challenge-response passwords (beware issues with
# some PAM modules and threads)
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
# Change to no to disable tunnelled clear text passwords
#PasswordAuthentication yes
# Kerberos options
#KerberosAuthentication no
#KerberosGetAFSToken no
#KerberosOrLocalPasswd yes
#KerberosTicketCleanup yes
# GSSAPI options
#GSSAPIAuthentication no
#GSSAPICleanupCredentials yes
X11Forwarding yes
X11DisplayOffset 10
PrintMotd no
PrintLastLog yes
TCPKeepAlive yes
#UseLogin no
#MaxStartups 10:30:60
#Banner /etc/issue.net
# Allow client to pass locale environment variables
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*
Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
# Set this to 'yes' to enable PAM authentication, account processing,
# and session processing. If this is enabled, PAM authentication will
# be allowed through the ChallengeResponseAuthentication and
# PasswordAuthentication.  Depending on your PAM configuration,
# PAM authentication via ChallengeResponseAuthentication may bypass
# the setting of "PermitRootLogin without-password".
# If you just want the PAM account and session checks to run without
# PAM authentication, then enable this but set PasswordAuthentication
# and ChallengeResponseAuthentication to 'no'.
UsePAM no
```

Thx for any hint in advance.

Answer (score 0):

How to generate public key?
Maybe try `ssh-key -t rsa`.